# Neo4j simple Cypher query takes 30 to 60 minutes or never completes?

Tags: neo4j

I have 3 types of nodes (all with labels O, PI, P). Only O and PI nodes can connect to each other, and PI can connect to P. I have about 10,000 nodes and 13,000 relationships in my DB.

I have created indexes for every field for each member, but if I run the queries below, it takes either 30 min for the first one or it never returns on the second one. Neo4j cant be this slow can it ? My database is less than 4MB in size and I want to add 5 GB of data but I can't even get good performance yet. Can anyone tell me what the problem is ? I looked at similar StackOverflow questions but they all hadnt created indexes or used labels. What gives ?

This query takes 30+ minutes

```
MATCH  (oj:O {name:"blah")-->(mpi:PI)-->(x:P {sys:"foo"})   ,  mpi-->(z:O ) 
RETURN oj,mpi,x LIMIT 100
```

This one runs forever, it seems:

```
MATCH (oj:O {name:"blah")-->(mpi:PI)-->(x:P {sys:"foo"})  ,  mpi-->(z:O )  
, oj-->(pii:PI)-->(pp:P {name:"fubar"} ) , pii-->(lo:O {text:"something"})
return oj,mpi,pii,lo LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Actually, this looks like an error on the part of Neo4j's browser. I can run these queries on the API really fast. Not sure why the browser piece is broken

Comment: Did you by chance zoom in with cmd-minus? if so try to restore to normal screen size

Comment: Can you show your indexes ? Output of :schema?

Comment: Did you try to run them in the Neo4j-Shell? Can you check the javascript console of the browser if you see any errors?

Comment: I will try the neo4j shell and let you know. I didnt know about :schema , pretty good to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by the Neo4j browser. Queries were taking an extremely long time in it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

When querying the Neo4j API with Cypher, the query execution plan is cached by extracting the parameters of the query. The query itself only needs to build its execution plan once. That's one factor, as with the browser you are not parametrizing the query. The second factor is data transfer between the browser and Neo4j.

Either of these factors isn't enough of an explanation for the 30 minute response times for those queries on your dataset. 4MB of data can be reasonably loaded into memory. Your query isn't what I would call complex or non-linear scaling.

This is most likely an issue with your browser's memory usage. I would try returning back just properties of your objects instead of the graph data. The LIMIT 100 doesn't prevent the relationships existing between the nodes to be loaded, so even for 100 rows of nodes, you could have many more relationships.